# End execution without script closure by keypress?

Tags: loops, return, autohotkey, break, nested-function

### Question

- Basically, the title says it all!  How do I stop execution of my hotkey via a hotkey?
- How do I do so without closing the script?
- How do I explicitly set a hotkey to take priority over a specific loop?

### Explanation

I have a loop that executes several hundred times (code attached), and I would like to create a kill switch.  I don't want to have to re-open the script if I stop it running, and I need to have lengthy sleeps, so I can fool with the mouse, as it is.

I'm looking at various pages, such as [tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) and [break](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Break.htm).

### What I've tried

For example, should I name my loop somehow?  Because `Break` takes no parameters, I'm thinking: there's no way to specify what to break.

Another example: should I add a hotkey into my loop to break?  If so, how do I do that?  Just throw `^!p::` into a nest under each hotkey?  Or is there another way to add a hotkey to a hotkey (for example, with `GetKeyState`)?

### Answer format

If possible, please ***show don't tell***  your answers, using the following code:

```
^!i::
{
    Loop 1300
    {
        Send ^+{PrintScreen}
        Sleep 1500
        MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 100, 600, 400
        Sleep 1000
        Send 1
        Sleep 500
    }
    Return
}
^!o::
{
    Loop 1323
    {
        Send ^+{PrintScreen}
        Sleep 1500
        MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 200, 600, 400
        Sleep 1000
        Send 1
    }
    Return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a controlled stop, i.e. at a certain point in the script, then you could use a hotkey to set a variable and test that variable in the script. When the variable has been set and the IF statement is true, you reset that variable and exit the loop. Otherwise, you could kill the script at a random point through the reload command. This way the script is closed, but immediately reopened.

```
^!i::
MyStopVariable:=0 ; Set the variable to 0
Loop 1300
{
    If MyStopVariable
        Exit ; Or Break if you want to finish something of after the loop
    Send ^+{PrintScreen}
    Sleep 1500
    MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 200, 600, 400
    Sleep 1000
    If MyStopVariable
        Exit ; Or Break if you want to finish something of after the loop
    Sleep 500
}
Return

^!o::
MyStopVariable:=0 ; Set the variable to 0
Loop 1323
{
    If MyStopVariable
        Exit ; Or Break if you want to finish something of after the loop
    Send ^+{PrintScreen}
    Sleep 1500
    MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 200, 600, 400
    Sleep 1000
    If MyStopVariable
        Exit ; Or Break if you want to finish something of after the loop
    Send 1
}
Return

^!s:: ; Ctrl+Alt+s = stop
MyStopVariable:=1
Return
```

Alternatively, you could use your original code and add a reload.

```
^!s:: ; Ctrl+Alt+s = stop
    Reload
Return
```

Comment: You're pretty active on AHK.  Are you a designer?  I'm sorry I had not attached code to the question, initially.

Comment: Robert, You're amazing.  This is wonderful.  It works flawlessly.